# creating thumbnail image through ffmpeg.exe

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am creating thumbnail image(small size) from a big image. for same images it unable to create the thumbnail. if i move the image from one place to another it works.

case:

if image x is created in year 2000  and i tried to extract thumbnail from that and let i failed. then i moved the same image to another place and again try to extracted the thumbanil and it successfully extracted the thumbnail. even if i am again transforming the same image to the same place it is working.

Edit: The command is:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/tools/converter/ffmpeg.exe
   -i "\\myip\knowledge base\videos\user_62\RHSSNet_Image_Library\images\Touchport_II\CD302_14_TPII_17in_PPR_Scanner.jpg" 
   -y -f mjpeg -s 72x92 -vframes 1
   -an c:/xampp/htdocs/jcert6/seyretfiles/uploads/thumbnails/user_62/user_62_tz2jliomkfunsrhd1291976903_0.jpg –
```

While debugging, I found that if any images do not have created date is not processed by the ffmpeg and generate error image codec parameter.

is it possible to process images without having a create date in ffmpeg???

Comment: 1) show the commands and paths used 2) this question need editing

Comment: So, exactly how is this programming related?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I don't see how the lack of a "create date" would cause an error in ffmpeg. What is the actual error? You should show the ffmpeg command you used and the complete ffmpeg console output/log. Provide a sample input file if possible so we can attempt to duplicate whatever issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder permissions and/or the path to the original file and the thumbnail. If it work by changing the location, this is the problem. Just guessing though cause do not have enough info.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. file paths are correct. i am still finding the solution.

Comment: What about the folder/file permission, do you have the right to read the source file and save the output file?